# Plotting median values of different data files (with gnuplot)

Tags: graph, plot, statistics, gnuplot

I have 4 different data files (for seasons) and already managed to make boxplots with median and stuff.

But now I'd like to show a development over the seasons with a simple line. 
I want gnuplot to plot the median values (and maybe quartils or standard deviations) of the 4 seasons and connect them via linespoints.

The values are in 4 separate data files in one column - for each column there is one median (and quartils...). I also want to ignore the first few entries.

I have tried the command `stats` but I always get an error here:

```
stats 'VARIANTE 1\Habitate\Äschen\Vergleich\FRU\WUA_Vergleich.dat' u 2 every ::5 label  "Ist_FRU"
stats 'VARIANTE 1\Habitate\Äschen\Vergleich\SOM\WUA_Vergleich.dat' u 2 every ::5 label "Ist_SOM"
stats 'VARIANTE 1\Habitate\Äschen\Vergleich\HER\WUA_Vergleich.dat' u 2 every ::5 label "Ist_HER"
stats 'VARIANTE 1\Habitate\Äschen\Vergleich\WIN\WUA_Vergleich.dat' u 2 every ::5 label "Ist_WIN"
```

I defined special `xtics` here:

```
set xtics ("Fru" 1, "Som" 2, "Her" 3, "Win" 4) scale 0.0  out font ",9"
```

and later wanted to plot that data:

```
plot \
 (1):median_Ist_FRU notitle linestyle 1, \
 (2):median_Ist_SOM notitle linestyle 1, \
 (3):median_Ist_HER notitle linestyle 1, \
 (4):median_Ist_WIN notitle linestyle 1
```

I guess I am not understanding the commands `stats` or `plot` properly, and the solution might be pretty simple for an experienced user - but I have tried many different things and nothing worked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the wrong syntax for the `stats` command (would have been helpful if you had provided the error message). You must use `name`, the rest is convenience:

```
tmpl = 'VARIANTE 1\Habitate\Äschen\Vergleich\%s\WUA_Vergleich.dat'
stats sprintf(tmpl, "FRU") u 2 every ::5 name "Ist_FRU_"
stats sprintf(tmpl, "SOM") u 2 every ::5 name "Ist_SOM_"
stats sprintf(tmpl, "HER") u 2 every ::5 name "Ist_HER_"
stats sprintf(tmpl, "WIN") u 2 every ::5 name "Ist_WIN_"
```

The plotting part is a bit tricky:

```
reset
# these are some test values
Ist_FRU_median = 1
Ist_SOM_median = 0.5
Ist_HER_median = 1.5
Ist_WIN_median = 1.2

set xtics ("Fru" 1, "Som" 2, "Her" 3, "Win" 4) scale 0.0
quartil="FRU SOM HER WIN"
set samples 4
set xrange[0.8:4.2]
plot '+' using ($0+1):(value('Ist_'.word(quartil, int($0+1)).'_median')) with linespoints title ''
```

Rough explanation of the script: Usually gnuplot can connect points with lines only when they appear in the same data file.

To simulate that, I use the special file name `+`, which generates a number of samples in the specified range (the `xrange` must be set in order to use `+`). I use four samples (`set samples 4`), the number of the current sample can be accessed with $0 (or column(0)) in the `using` statement. The sample number goes from `0` to `3`.

`quartil` holds four words, which are extracted later to construct the variable name. The first word has the index `1`, therefore I use `word(quartil, $0+1)`.

If a variable name is known as string, its value can be accessed by `value(string)`.

The result with the test data is:
[image]